# How to declare manually uint512_t in boost?

Tags: c++, boost, biginteger

i wanna declare this:

```
uint512_t qwe = 0x5FBFF498AA938CE739B8E022FBAFEF40563F6E6A3472FC2A514C0CE9DAE23B7E;
```

but c++ don't think so(vscode hints too):

```
integer constant is too large for its type
```

and its print like:

```
x: 0x514c0ce9dae23b7e
```

can you help me please?

Comment: You need to construct it from a string. Did you try `uint512_t qwe{"0x5FBFF498AA938CE739B8E022FBAFEF40563F6E6A3472FC2A514C0CE9DAE23B7E"}`? I didn't try it but the boost big number types do have string constructors.

Comment: @ypnos thank you! it is works and i didn't know about this constructor thing before :0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [user-defined literals](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/lits.html) to initialize [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) numbers, for example:

```
uint512_t qwe =
     0x5FBFF498AA938CE739B8E022FBAFEF40563F6E6A3472FC2A514C0CE9DAE23B7E_cppui512;
```

Alternatively, you could use a constructor [from string](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html), but this is less efficient as it will require run time parsing. It can be useful if the number is not a compile-time constant.